# Using Dropdownlist selected value in IF statement MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC. I am trying for Cascading Dropdownlist in ASP.NET MVC 4. My problem is I want to access the selected countryid in @foreach loop

```
@Html.DropDownList("ddlCountry", new SelectList(@Model.Countries, "CountryId", "CountryName"))


$("#ddlCountry").change(function () {
        @foreach (var item in @Model.States.Select(x=>x.countryId = ?))
        {

        }
});
```

How can I substitute countryId with the question mark above, so that I can filter the states

Thanks in Advance

Thanks

SRRIN

Comment: You cant (javascript is client side code, razor is server side code). Your `change` function needs to call a controller method to return the `States` based on the selected Country ID (or you need to store all states in a javascipt variable - but that would only be a reasonable option if you had only a handful of states)

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627421/better-way-to-load-2-dropdown-in-mvc/28640420#28640420) might help you to get started with creating cascading dropdown lists

Answer (score 0):

you can get the value in jquery by this

```
$("#ddlCountry option:selected").text();
```

As @Stephen said you cannot get the value of selected option using razor. Because the razor code is executed before page load.

A work around would be

```
$("#ddlCountry").change(function () {
 var selectedVal= $("#ddlCountry option:selected").text();
 var list = @Model.States.Tojson();

});
```

then use [inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/) for doing further operations

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all.
As Stephen and Nikitesh stated, javascript variable are not accessible inside razor scripts. So I succeeded with following approach.

```
var selectedCountryId = $("#ddlCountry").val();
var states = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.States));
for (var i = 0; i < states .length; i++) {
if (states [i].countryid == selectedCountryId ) {
... populate states here
}
}
```

Thanks

SRRIN

Comment: Yes, Its right also same thing i mentioned in my answer's comment.

Answer (score -1):

you can use dropdown selected value and pass in your query as:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ddlCountry", new SelectList(@Model.Countries,"CountryId", "CountryName"))
$("#ddlCountry").change(function () {
var countryId=parseInt($(this).val());
    @foreach (var item in @Model.States.Select(x=>x.countryId = countryId))
    {

    }
});
```

Comment: Try it, and take note of the error - `countryId` is a client side javascript variable which does not exist when the `foreach` block is run on the server - its not in scope!

Comment: you can try to put states into another variable. var states='@Model.States';
and use the $.each jquery function.