# Combining multiple fields in dropdown list with MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I am working on video site. I have no idea how to combine the two fields from different models in dropdownlist.

Models are:

```
VideoDM(have subcategoryid as fk)
CategoryDM
SubCategoryDM(have categoryid as fk)
```

Subcategory loads on video views in dropdown as can be seen from controller:

```
 [Authorize]
  public ActionResult Create()
  {
   ViewBag.SubCategoryId = new SelectList(db.SubCategory, "SubCategoryId", "Name");
   return View();
   }
```

And dropdown for view:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("SubCategoryId", String.Empty)
```

My question is, if there is a way to combine the both category and subcategory in dropdownlist like:

```
category>>subcategory1
        >>subcategory2
        >>subcategory3
```

Comment: Sound like you want cascading dropdowns (the first displays `Category`, and the second displays `SubCategories` based on the selection of the first)

Comment: Lots of examples on the web for how do that - [one example here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627421/better-way-to-load-2-dropdown-in-mvc/28640420#28640420)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have two separate dropdown lists one for category and one for subcategory and your subcategory dropdown list will be populated on the select change event of the category dropdown list.

Comment: thanks for guide,,,,yes i had thoughts about that, but i dont want to populate them in defferent ddls,,,

Comment: You could design a 'menu' sort of a list (ul) where in if you hover over a category, subcategories will popup. You can iterate through your data lists in the Razor view to create that list.