# MVC (Razor) Filter DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm new to MVC and JavaScript and I have a question about DropDownList.

I Build a program of "Car Renting" and I have a View that allow adding new Car to the inventory.

The view include 2 dropdownlists (see below):

```
 <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("ManufacturerId", string.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ManufacturerId)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ModelId)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("ModelId", string.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ModelId)
    </div>
```

I want that when user select a manufacturer for example (Alfa Romeo) the "model" list box will display only "Alfa Mito" models and not the full list...

My Controller function send to the view the Model List using ViewBag see below:

```
public ActionResult AddNewCar()
    {
        ViewBag.ManufacturerId = new SelectList(db.Manufacturers, "ManufacturerId", "ManufacturerName");
        ViewBag.ModelId = new SelectList(db.Models, "ModelId", "ModelName");

        ViewBag.BranchId = new SelectList(db.Branchs, "BranchId", "BranchName");

        return View();
    }
```

Please advice.

Thanks,
Almog

Comment: You need javascript/jquery to generate cascading dropdownlists. Refer [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627421/better-way-to-load-2-dropdown-in-mvc/28640420#28640420).

Comment: You can use Ajax to post the manufactureID to controller action and return the models for it and rebind the model dropdownlist.

Answer (score 0):

call below action method from jquery on dropdown change event.

```
 public List<carmodels> PopulateState(int manufacturerId)
        {
            var carmodelsObj = (from st in dc.Carmodels
                        where st.manufacturerId.Equals(manufacturerId)
                        select st).ToList();

            return (carmodelsObj);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to repopulate/populate your `ModelId` dropdown on every time when your first dropdown changes (using `jquery`). Do following:

- Get the `ManufactureId` from first dropdown on change event. and place an `ajax` call to repopulate your second dropdown.

  ```
  $("#ManufactureId").change(function() {

    var manufacturerId = manufacturer$('#ManufacturerId').val();


    $.ajax({url: "~/Car/GetCarsByManufacturer", success: function(result){

        //re populate your second dropdown here
        //hint: you may use response.id for value
    }});
  ```

  });
- Create a function in your controller that returns Car Models, based on selected. (call this function in previous step using ajax).

  ```
  public List<carmodels> GetCarsByManufacturer(int manufacturerId)
  {
      var carmodelsObj = (from st in dc.Carmodels
                  where st.manufacturerId.Equals(manufacturerId)
                  select st).ToList();

      return (carmodelsObj);

  }
  ```