# Change SelectList of DropDownList

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have 2 DropDownList items in my View. SelectList of DropDownList1 is taken from Database once and does not change further. Every time when user changes selected index of DropDownList1, SelectedList of DropDownList2 has to be changed too.

Here's the way I'm trying to implement this feature:

```
@{
    var selectList1 = MyApp.Models.Model1.GetAll();
    Int32 selectedId = 0;
    @Html.DropDownListFor(s => selectedId, new SelectList(selectList1, 
                                                          "dataValueField1",
                                                          "dataTextField1") as SelectList, 
                          "Choose item...")
    var selectList2 =    MyApp.Models.Model2.GetItemsById(selectedId);
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model2 => model2.SelectedItem2, new  SelectList(selectList2, 
                                                                          "dataValueField2",
                                                                          "dataTextField2") as SelectList,
                          "Choose item2..")
}
```

I know, that I have to update selectList2 variable every time when selected index of DropDownList1 is changed and to update DropDownList2 after that.
So, what is the best way to implement this behavior?

Comment: You need to use javascript to handle the `.change()` event of the first one and use ajax to update the second one. [Refer this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627421/better-way-to-load-2-dropdown-in-mvc/28640420#28640420)

Comment: Voted up for stephen's option. Juste dont forget to add a reference to the jquery library if it is not done.

Comment: refer here http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/creating-simple-cascading-dropdownlist-in-mvc-4-using-razor/

Answer (score 2):

When the dropdown list named ddlBusinessAreaId changes, it emptys the items of the dropdown list named ddlFunctionalAreaId.  Then it makes a post request to a method named GetFunctionalAreas that exists on the blah controller.  Then it loops through the results and adds them as items to the ddlFunctionalAreaId dropdown.

```
$('#ddlFunctionalAreaId').change(function () {            
        $('#BusinessOwner').val("");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'GetBusinessOwner',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { id: $('#ddlFunctionalAreaId').val() },

            success: function (businessOwner) {
                if (businessOwner != null) {
                    $("#BusinessOwner_UserName").val(businessOwner.UserName);
                    $("#BusinessOwner_DisplayName").val(businessOwner.DisplayName);
                }
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                //alert('Failed to retrieve Business Owner.' + ex);
            }
        })
    });


    $('#ddlBusinessAreaId').change(function () {
        $('#ddlFunctionalAreaId').empty();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("../../blah/blah/GetFunctionalAreas")',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { id: $('#ddlBusinessAreaId').val() },

            success: function (functionalAreas) {
                $.each(functionalAreas, function (i, functionalArea) {
                    $("#ddlFunctionalAreaId").append('<option value="' + functionalArea.Value + '">' +
                         functionalArea.Text + '</option>');
                });
                $('#ddlFunctionalAreaId').trigger('change');

            },
            error: function (ex) {
                //alert('Failed to retrieve functional areas.' + ex);
            }
        })
    });
```

Comment: You need to add a reference to a jquery library

Answer (score 1):

I must use Jquery to detect the change 
[.change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/) in the first fields. Write a Controller service for update the second dropdown through the Ajax method. Check this example [An ASP.NET MVC Cascading Dropdown List](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/883701/An-ASP-NET-MVC-Cascading-Dropdown-List)

Answer (score 1):

You must use jquery to make to the server side and bind the data to second dropdown. Here is the sample

```
         @{
         ViewBag.Title = "Classic Cascading DDL";
          }

@using (Html.BeginForm("IndexDDL", "Home", FormMethod.Post, 
new { id = "CountryStateFormID", 
      data_stateListAction = @Url.Action("StateList") })) {

   <fieldset>
    <legend>Country/State</legend>
    @Html.DropDownList("Countries", ViewBag.Country as SelectList,
        "Select a Country", new { id = "CountriesID" })
    <div id="StatesDivID" >
        <label for="States">States</label>
        <select id="StatesID"  name="States"></select>
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="SubmitID" />
    </p>
    </fieldset>
  }
```

c#

```
     public SelectList GetCountrySelectList() 
     {
       var countries = Country.GetCountries();
       return new SelectList(countries.ToArray(),
                    "Code",
                    "Name");
     }

  public ActionResult IndexDDL() 
  {
   ViewBag.Country = GetCountrySelectList();
   return View();
  }
```

Javascript function

```
           $(function () { 

$('#StatesDivID').hide(); 
$('#SubmitID').hide(); 

$('#CountriesID').change(function () { 
    var URL = $('#CountryStateFormID').data('stateListAction'); 
    $.getJSON(URL + '/' + $('#CountriesID').val(), function (data) { 
        var items = '<option>Select a State</option>'; 
        $.each(data, function (i, state) { 
            items += "<option value='" + state.Value + "'>" + state.Text + "</option>"; 
            // state.Value cannot contain ' character. We are OK because state.Value = cnt++; 
        }); 
        $('#StatesID').html(items); 
        $('#StatesDivID').show(); 

    }); 
}); 

$('#StatesID').change(function () { 
    $('#SubmitID').show(); 
}); 
});
```