# cascading html helper dropdownlistfor's in HTML razor for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

Is there any convenient way to cascade multiple @Html.DropDownListFor ? i found [>this<](http://www.sidecreative.com/Blog/Entry/Cascading-dropdown-lists-with-MVC4-and-jQuery) article that explained how to do it with partial views, but im not sure how to do it that way for multiple dropdown's cascading each other and i would like to keep things to 1 viewmodel too. The other implementation that i saw was by adding  to a first @Html.DropDownListFor an @onchange javascript function that created more dropdownlists by calling an ajax function which returned the the options to add to the new drop down list, these new drop down lists were created using the html < select > tag, to which another @onchange javascript function was bound to keep cascading more of these. However i would like to know if there's a way of doing this by using only the DropDownListFor from the html helper and avoiding the html < select > tag.

I was trying to do something like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(vm => vm.Var0, dataBase.fetchStartinOptions())
@Html.DropDownListFor(vm => vm.Var1, dataBase.fetchOptions(@Model.Var0))
@Html.DropDownListFor(vm => vm.Var2, dataBase.fetchOptions(@Model.Var1))
```

where "database.fetchOptions(x)" returns a "List < SelectListItem >"

But i dont know if that's possible at all, i was trying to find a way to do it with jquery and what not but couldnt find anything. The problem is that i cannot find a way to re-load the  subsequent html.DropDownLists with the value from the previous one.

Thank you for your time.

--josepablo

Comment: Razor is server side code that is parsed on the server before its sent to the client. It cannot react to changes in the client. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627421/better-way-to-load-2-dropdown-in-mvc/28640420#28640420) gives a jquery example of cascading dropdownlists

Comment: @StephenMuecke Alright I've been looking at your other answer but there is something I do not understand. After you repopulate your variable 'Cities' inside the javascript with:

      `cities.append($('<option></option>').val(item.Value).text(item.Text));`


Does the

 `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CityID, Cities, "Select City")`


automatically changes its list of Cities to the new list inside the javascript variable? or am i missing something?

Comment: Yes. `cities` is a reference to the dropdown list created by the `@Html.DropDownListFor()` helper method. The script first removes existing options (using the `.empty()` function) then add new options using the `.append()` function

Comment: ok thanks a lot! your answer really helped. I had trouble because i wasn't sure how the htmlhelpers worked, also had trouble understanding how razor code worked only server side and the html/javascript was what stayed client side, but well. Do you happen to know where the code for he htmlhelpers is located? I'd like to take a look at that.

Comment: @StephenMuecke and I'm curious about something, how does `cities` work as a reference? is it because when you cache it with `var cities= $('#cities');` the variable `cities` saves the id of its cached content too and not just the content? because i find it funny that if i try to do `cities = anotherVarWithaList` it doesnt update the dropdownlist but with `cities.append(anotherVarWithaList)` it does work.

Comment: You can see the [source code here](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/SelectExtensions.cs)

Comment: `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CityID, ...)` creates html `<select>` element with `id="CityID"`, then `var cities= $('#cities');` assigns that element to the variable `cities`.