# Cascading Drop Down List in MVC w/ SQL Database

Tags: mysql, ajax, asp.net-mvc, cascadingdropdown

I have two drop down lists which are District & School. I would like whenever I choose a district from the list, the values that are in the school list will change at the same time. I am using ajax to try and post the data to another controller but the school list does not change at all. It contains the names of all schools no matter which district I select. I am thinking it has something to do with the line `Schools = new SelectList(db.Schools.ToList(), "schoolID", "name")`in my `SchoolDistrictInformation` controller. Here is what I am working with so far:

**The security code is a code that must be entered and corresponds with the selected district. It must match with the code in the database or the form will not be submitted.**

**View Model:**

```
public class DistrictSchoolListViewModel
{
    public SelectList Districts { get; set; }
    public SelectList Schools { get; set; }
    public string SelectedSchool { get; set; }
    public string SelectedDistrict { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This code is required")]
    public string DistrictCode { get; set; }
}
```

**Controllers:**

```
public ActionResult SchoolDistrictInformation()
{
    var viewModel = new DistrictSchoolListViewModel()
    {
        Districts = new SelectList(db.Districts.ToList(), "leaID", "name"),
        Schools = new SelectList(db.Schools.ToList(), "schoolID", "name")
    };
    return View(viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetSchools(DistrictSchoolListViewModel model)
{
    var selectedDistrict = model.SelectedDistrict;
    var schools = findSchools(selectedDistrict);
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> filteredSchools = 
    schools.Select(m => new SelectListItem { Text = m.name, Value = m.schoolID.ToString() });
    return PartialView("SchoolDistrictInformation", filteredSchools);
}
```

**School Table Query:**

```
    internal IQueryable<School> findSchools(string district)
    {
        var query = from School in db.Schools
                    where School.leaID.Equals(district)
                    select School;
        return query;
    }
```

**School District Information View:**

```
@model Staff_Form.Models.DistrictSchoolListViewModel 

<h2>Select District and School from list</h2>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#SelectedDistrict').on('change', function () {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'Controller/GetSchools',
        data: $(this).val(),
        success: function (response) {
            $('#SelectedSchool').html(response);
        }
    });

});

</script>

<div>
    <form action="@Url.Action("StaffInformation", "Staff")" method="get">
        District: @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedDistrict, Model.Districts, "----Select----")
        Security Code: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DistrictCode) <br />
        School: @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedSchool, Model.Schools, "----Select----")
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

**Get Schools View:**

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>
@{ Layout = null;}

@foreach (var school in Model)
{
    <option value="@school.Value">@school.Text</option>
}
```

I appreciate any and all help given towards the solution of this question. Thank you!

Comment: Does the filtered schools linq query returnt he correct list?

Comment: you need to define your `data:` param better.. `data: {SelectedDistrict: $(this).val()`

Comment: from testing, and use of breakpoints, it looks like theres a problem with my ajax call as when I select a district from the drop down, it doesn't even make it to the query. @Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is before the the element with `id="SelectedDistrict"` and not wrapped in `$(document).ready()` so your attaching an event to an element which does not even exist at that point.

Move the script to the bottom of the page (immediately before the closing `</body?` tag and/or wrap it inside [document.ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() { // or $(function() {
    $('#SelectedDistrict').on('change', function () {
        ....
    });
});
```

Side note: Update your version of jquery to a recent version and consider returning json to populate your 2nd dropdown (refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627421/better-way-to-load-2-dropdown-in-mvc/28640420#28640420))

Comment: I've tried wrapping in the document.ready & have tried suggestions in the post you linked. None of these have changed what the program does as far as I can see. I have placed some breakpoints and it seems as if the code doesn't make it into the script. I think my `SchoolDistrictInformation` controller might have something to do with it. My school table is already populated with all the names from the School table.

Comment: I changed my version from 3.0.2 to 1.10.2 and it goes into the script now. everything else that I have mentioned is still a problem.

Comment: Which problem are you referring to. You have now modified you script to add options based on the return data being json, but the `GetSchools()` method returns html (a partial view) so of course it wont work. In any case you have decorated it with `[HttpPost]` (despite it being a GET method) but `$.getJSON()` call a GET method (hence its name). If you going to use the code in the links, then study it and do it correctly.

Comment: Oh man, I missed the `[HttpPost]` since it's so easy to scroll by. I changed the return partial to a return json when I changed the JSON method I just forgot to update it, sorry about that. Where I am currently is that the value of the selection I make from the first dropbox is not being saved to the view model / passed to `GetSchools()`. So when I use `model.SelectedDistrict` to query the database, it's value is `null`. Because of this, the 2nd dropbox changes to having one selection with the text "Please Select" since that's what is in the text value in the script.

Comment: I have rolled back you edit to the original because that is what my answer was based on. You cant completely change the question making everyone answer completely useless. Your original code did not work for the reasons in my answer (the script never fires because it's not inside `$(document).ready()`

Comment: If your still having problems, I suggest you look at this [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GTYuJV) I created for another answer - it has 3 cascading dropdownlists

Comment: Thanks, your code helped me realize that my controller was taking `SchoolDistrictViewModel model` as a parameter instead of the value that `getJSON` was passing to it. So now it takes a parameter of `string id` and it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

You should include the property name when you pass the district back to the GetSchools action

```
$('#SelectedDistrict').on('change', function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'Controller/GetSchools',
        data: { SelectedDistrict: $(this).val() },
        success: function (response) {
            $('#SelectedSchool').html(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Adding the property name didn't change anything, if it helps any, my code isn't even reaching the query, it's just staying in the School District View

Comment: it definitely changed something.. you just have other issues..  make sure your `url:` is correct also.. best to use`@Url.Action`   like `url: '@Url.Action("GetSchools")'`

Comment: Changed that as well. That's a better way to look at it though. It's still not making it over to GetSchools though, maybe it's not doing the "on change" correctly?

Comment: put an `alert("change called");` as the first line in your function and see if it's being called.. looks like you're using a really old version of jQuery.. that might be an issue

Comment: okay, so it's not even going into the ajax function. && yes I saw that about 30 mins ago, so I changed it to version 1.11.1