# Get selectedIndex of dropdown using c# (Razor)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Is it possible to get the selectedIndex of a dropdown in a view using C# (Razor). For example, can I fill a second dropdown based off the selectedIndex of another dropdown using Razor?

```
@model ViewModel

<select id="dropdown1">
//Options
</select>

<select id="dropdown2">
//Options
</select>

@if(//The selectedIndex of dropdown1 == 4)
{
//Fill dropdown 2 from model
}
```

When using Javascript, I am a little off as well:

```
            <script>
            if (dropdown1.selectedIndex === 3)
            {
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {

                }
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: You're confusing client-side code and server-side code.  When do you want that to run?

Comment: When a user selects an option in dropdown1

Comment: Then you need to handle the change event in Javascript.

Comment: Okay, having trouble filling my dropdown from a model with javascript

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: I am just not understanding how to insert the values into dropdown2 only when the selectedIndex of dropdown1 is something. I added a little edit

Comment: Are you trying to do a Cascading DropDown (fill a dropdown based on selected dropdown item)? We're using http://www.dnasir.com/github/jquery-cascading-dropdown/demo.html in our project.

Comment: Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627421/better-way-to-load-2-dropdown-in-mvc/28640420#28640420) for a example of  cascading dropdownlists

Comment: How about doing it with javascript generated by razor/c#? If you know every dropdown2 value list for each possible dropdown1 value. No postback required.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a ajax call when the first dropdown changes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getDropDown2Data(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetDropDown2Data", "YourController")',
        data: { Id: id },
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            var items = "";
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                items += "<option value=\"" + item.Name + "\">" + item.Id + "</option>";
            });

            $("#dropDown2").html(items);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dropDown2").change(function () {
        var id = $("#dropDown2").val();
        getDropDown2Data(id);
    });
});
</script>


 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Id, new SelectList(Model.Model1, "Id", "Name"), "Select")

 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Id, new SelectList(Model.Model2, "Id", "Name"), "Select")
```

And you action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetDropDown2Data(id id)
{

  //Here you get your data, ie Model2

   return Json(Model2, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Is this possible without doing a `@Html.DropDownListFor`. What if there was a preexisting, regular dropdown like this: `<select id="dropdown2">
//Options
</select>`

Comment: Yes, it is possible, the @Html.DropDownListFor just creates a select in Html, so if you have the id of the select it should work.