# Load 2 dropdown list in MVC page load

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have create MVC application with 2 dropdown lists.

One is Country list and other is states list.

Here i want to load my country like "India" and corresponding states in page load action result in MVC.

And i need to disable the country list dropdown once it load the states dropdown.

Can you guys help me on this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need javascript/jquery (refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627421/better-way-to-load-2-dropdown-in-mvc/28640420#28640420) for an example). Alternatively you need to submit a form after selecting the country and display a new view where you can select the states (but why disable the country dropdownlist?)

Comment: I need jQuery. I have to load it in mvc page load.

Answer (score 0):

For populating dropdown lists first you have to define ViewBag(s) in your action method:

```
    ViewBag.Category = new SelectList(_categoryService.GetCategories(), "CatId", "CatTitle");
ViewBag.SubCategory = new SelectList(_subCategoryService.GetSubCategories(), "SubCatId", "SubCatTitle");
```

Then inside your view:

```
<!-- Category -->
<div class="form-group clearfix" id="group-section">
   <label><span>Category</span></label>
   <div class="col-md-offset-7 col-md-5 col-xs-offset-4 col-xs-8" id="group" name="group">
        @Html.DropDownList("Category", (SelectList)ViewBag.Category, "-- Select ---", new { @class = "form-control", id = "rdbCategory" })
   </div>
</div>
<!-- End form-group category -->
<!-- SubCategory -->
<div class="form-group clearfix" id="group-section">
   <label><span>SubCategory</span></label>
   <div class="col-md-offset-7 col-md-5 col-xs-offset-4 col-xs-8" id="group" name="group">
         @Html.DropDownList("SubCategory", (SelectList)ViewBag.SubCategory, "-- Select ---", new { @class = "form-control", id = "rdbSubCategory", disabled = "true" })
   </div>
</div>
```

Then for disbaling at the first time:

```
$('#rdbCategory').change(function() {
                $('#rdbSubCategory').prop('disabled', function(i, v) {
                    $('#rdbSubCategory').empty();
                    $('#rdbSubCategory').append($('<option></option>').text('-- Select ---'));
                    $('#rdbSubCategory').val($('#rdbSubCategory option:first').val());
                    return !v;
                });
});
```