# How to filter dropdown boxes based mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have three dropdown boxes in my View with the code

```
@Html.DropDownList("EventGroupTitle", ViewData["groupList"] as List<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.DropDownList("EventGroupName", ViewData["groupNameList"] as List<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.DropDownList("EventTypeOne", ViewData["typeList"] as List<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

And my controller GET action method is

```
   public ActionResult Create()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> liEventGroups = new List<SelectListItem>();
        List<SelectListItem> liEventTypes = new List<SelectListItem>();
        List<SelectListItem> liEventGroupNames = new List<SelectListItem>();

        // pull results from DB and assign them to the above variables           

        ViewData["typeList"] = liEventTypes;
        ViewData["groupList"] = liEventGroups;
        ViewData["groupNameList"] = liEventGroupNames;
        return View();
    }
```

In the database, there is a one-to-many relationship between `EventGroupTitle` and `EventGroupNames`. As an example, a group title may be `Doctor` and the group names would be `Dr Joe`, `Dr Adrian`. Another group title would be `Nurse` and so the group names would be `Nurse Daniel`, `Nurse Dave`.

There is no actual foreign key setup, however there is a field in `GroupNames` that say what the `title` is.

So is there a way to do some sort of filtering on the dropboxes? If they select `Doctor` in the first dropbox, then I want only the doctors appearing in the second dropbox.

Comment: You need javascript/jquery to handle client side events. Search MVC cascading dropdwnlists, or look at this [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JofdB8) for an example

Comment: Is there a different function than `append`. When the page loads, the all possible choices are there in dropdownbox 2. When they change something in dropdownbox 1, your code works as expected but appends it to the second box. Is there a way to rewrite the entire dropdownbox?

Comment: Look at the example - you need ajax to call a server method to populate the second dropdown list based on the value of the first (the secons dropdown should initially be empty). Or if you want to initially load all options all options for the second dropdown and do it without ajax, look at the last option in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627421/better-way-to-load-2-dropdown-in-mvc/28640420#28640420)

Comment: If you post as an answer, I will accept it. Your example helped me achieved what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

I created cascading dropdown html helper that could be helpful here. It is available as [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mvc.CascadeDropDown/) and a source code with tests is on [github](https://github.com/alexanderar/Mvc.CascadeDropDown).

The usage is very simple. For example you have a country an city dropdowns
with the following model:

**Model**:

```
public class Model
{
    public int SelectedCountry {get;set;}
    public IList<SelectListItem> Countries {get;set;}
    public int SelectedCity {get;set;} 
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult GetCities(int country)
{
   //return IList<SelectListItem> of Cities based on a country that you get as a parameter
}
```

**View**

```
//First simple dropdown 
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.SelectedCountry, Model.Countries,
"Please select a Country", new {@class="form-control"})

//Dropdown list for SelectedCity property that depends on selection of SelectedCountry property
@Html.CascadingDropDownListFor( 
      expression: m => m.SelectedCity, 
      triggeredByProperty: m => m.SelectedCountry,  //Parent property that trigers dropdown data loading
      url: Url.Action("GetCities", "Home"),  //Url of action that returns dropdown data
      actionParam: "country",   //Parameter name for the selected parent value that url action receives
      optionLabel: "Please select a City", // Option label
      disabledWhenParrentNotSelected: true, //If true, disables dropdown until parrent dropdown selected
      htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" }) //Html attributes
```