# Ajax model filter on multi DropDownList bind

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, sitefinity-8

I have a problem which I'm not sure how to solve (code-wise) and I'd like to get some input from the community.

So, I have a page where I will display product details and these details will vary according to the values selected on a DropDownList (DDL).
So, for each product I have a collection of variations of said product which are identified by a UniqueId and by a JSON array of attribute uniqueIds, like this:

```
[
    {
        "AttributeId": "fe153d69-8ac1-6e0c-8793-ff0000804eb3",
        "AttributeValueId": "64163d69-8ac1-6e0c-8793-ff0000804eb3"
    },
    {
        "AttributeId": "00163d69-8ac1-6e0c-8793-ff0000804eb3",
        "AttributeValueId": "67163d69-8ac1-6e0c-8793-ff0000804eb3"
    }
]
```

What this tells me is that this particular variation has a `Days` attribute with a value of 5, a `Portions` attribute value of 4 and so on..

For this particular product I also have other values/variations with the same scheme.
Here are my possible values:

```
Days | Portions
  3        2
  3        4
  3        6
  5        4
```

Now, on my View I'm binding two DDLs to each of these attributes (one for days, one for Portions).

Here's my controller Method:

```
    public ActionResult Details(Guid productId)
    {
        CatalogManager catalogManager = CatalogManager.GetManager();
        EcommerceManager ecommerceManager = EcommerceManager.GetManager();

        ProductListWidgetModel model = new ProductListWidgetModel();
        model.Product = catalogManager.GetProduct(productId);

        //Read the variant properties
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        model.ProductVariations = catalogManager.GetProductVariations(productId).ToList();
        model.Portions = new List<SelectListItem>();
        model.Meals = new List<SelectListItem>();

        foreach (var item in model.ProductVariations)
        {
            List<AttributeValuePair> attributeValuePairs = serializer.Deserialize<List<AttributeValuePair>>(item.Variant);
            foreach (var attribute in attributeValuePairs)
            {
                if (catalogManager.GetProductAttribute(attribute.AttributeId).Title == "Portions")
                {
                    var attributes = catalogManager.GetProductAttributeValue(attribute.AttributeValueId);
                    if (!model.Portions.Exists(x => x.Value == attributes.Title))
                    {
                        model.Portions.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = attributes.Id.ToString(), Text = attributes.Title });
                    }
                }
                if (catalogManager.GetProductAttribute(attribute.AttributeId).Title == "Days")
                {
                    var attributes = catalogManager.GetProductAttributeValue(attribute.AttributeValueId);
                    if (!model.Meals.Exists(x => x.Value == attributes.Title))
                    {
                        model.Meals.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = attributes.Id.ToString(), Text = attributes.Title });
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return View("Detail", model);
    }
```

And my Model:

```
public class ProductListWidgetModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets all the messages.
    /// </summary>
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string SubTitle { get; set; }

    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public List<Product> ProductsList { get; set; }

    public List<ProductVariation> ProductVariations { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> Portions { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Meals { get; set; }
}
```

And also my View:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th id="row">@Html.DropDownList("MealsSelector", @Model.Meals } )</th>
        <td id="row">Middager</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th id="row">@Html.DropDownList("PortionsSelector", @Model.Portions)</th>
        <td id="row">Porsjoner</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But what I really need to do is have the Portions bound DDL only show the possible values based on the Days DDL, so if I selected 5 Days I should only have the choice of selecting 4 Portions on the Portions DDL.

How can I achieve this? Ideally I would prefer to have this done via Ajax or a simple LINQ filter to do this.

Can anyone guide me on how to bind these DDLs to one another?

Comment: You need javascript/jquery to handle the change event of the first dropdown, use ajax to call a controller method (passing the selected `Day`) and return the `Portions` for the selected `Selected` and update the options in the second dropdown list.

Comment: Hello @StephenMuecke that was my first approach, however I don't want to have to update the full page and call back the view, I'd like to update just the DropDown. Is that possible?

Comment: You just return json containing the values for the options. Refer [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627421/better-way-to-load-2-dropdown-in-mvc/28640420#28640420)