# Loading data from database in dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am doing my Application in MVC. I am new to MVC. I have 2 dropdown in my application. 2 dropdown data should be fetched from data base only . In my table i have 2 fields Business category and Business Name.

Sql Table

BusinessCategory  Businessname
Hospital          Eye Hospital
Hospital          Pediatric Hospital
Parlor            Green trends, naturals

In the first dropdown Business category will loaded from database. If they click hospital in the first dropdown automatically the second dropdown will be loaded the Business name which is under Hospital(Eye Hospital, Pediatric Hospital)

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

To load the first dropdown . My Controller code is

```
 public ActionResult WaitingList()
        {
            SYTEntities ca = new SYTEntities();
            IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = ca.tblBusinessCategories.Select(c => new SelectListItem
                {

                    Value = c.BusinessCategory,
                    Text = c.BusinessCategory

                });
            ViewBag.BusinessCategory = items;


            return View();
        }
```

My View code is

```
@model IEnumerable<SYTMain.Models.Search>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "WaitingList";

}
<div>
       @Html.DropDownList("BusinessCategory", "Select")
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are numerous answers on SO about how to create cascading dropdown lists including [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627421/better-way-to-load-2-dropdown-in-mvc/28640420#28640420)

Comment: Hi, i am referring both the field in same table. Is it possible to do?

Comment: This wont work with one table - you need 2 tables, one for the categories and one for the businesses (with a FK to the category)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use jQuery to simplify

```
<div id="business"></div>
<script>
       $("#BusinessCategory").change(function () {
           $.get("/lists/business/" + $("#BusinessCategory").val(), function (businessDropDown) {
                $("#business").html(businessDropDown);

            });
        });
</script>
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Business(int id) //Category id
{      
       //database logic
        ViewBag.Categories = categories;

        return PartialView();
}
```

PartialView Business.cshtml

```
@Html.DropDownList("Categories", "Select")
```

Comment: I am using only one table only. Is it possible to do with one table

Comment: One table in the database?

Comment: I don't see why not. What does your table look like?

Comment: For example a Employee table where supervisor is a foreign key to the id of the same table. You wouldn't need to normalize the Employee table to Parent and Child tables. There would need to be at least 1 null value for supervisor for example the CEO.

Comment: Thank you so much for ur reply. I got the solution for this question.