# how to bind my dropdownlist by json result?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, html.dropdownlistfor

my json string in developer tool network tab is:

```
"{\"1\":\"GJ_CITY1\",\"2\":\"GJ_CITY2\",\"3\":\"GJ_CITY3\",
  \"4\":\"GJ_CITY1\",\"5\":\"Aman\",\"6\":\"Aman\",
  \"7\":\"Aman\",\"8\":\"Aman\",\"9\":\"Alwar\"}"
```

i saw various articles but that doesn't work ,i am new to ajax data bindig and my mvc code is

```
$.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        datatype:"JSON",
        url: queryLink,
        async: true,
        success: function (result) {

            $('#Cities').html("");//clear before bind
            $.each(result, function (i, Cities) {
                $("#Cities").append($('<option value=\"" + key + "\">" + val + "</option>'));
            });
        }
});
```

my controller code is

```
 CitiesDao cities_obj = new CitiesDao();
        HybridNetworkHandoverdto obj = new HybridNetworkHandoverdto();
        var query1 = cities_obj.Details().Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(t => new CityDto
        {
            State_id = t.Field<long>("state_id"),
            State_name = t.Field<string>("state_name"),
            City_id = t.Field<long>("City_id"),
            City_name = t.Field<string>("City_name")
        }).ToList();
        ViewBag.cities = query1;
        Dictionary<string, string> abc = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (var item in query1)
        {
            abc.Add(item.City_id.ToString(),item.City_name);
        }

        //string jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(abc);
        var jsonResult = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var json = jsonResult.Serialize(abc);


        return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: what's the problem in binding?

Comment: Show your controller method that generates that result (you need to fix that first)

Comment: have you tried `JSON.parse()` to convert your string to actual JSON object?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tummt85d/1/

Comment: datatype:"json" is in ajax using jquery , no need to parse it @vijayP

Comment: Remove the `Dictionary` and `Serialize` code and adding the `ViewBag` property is nonsense. Change you query to return only the 2 properties you need in the view - `City_id` and `City_name` and then just `return Json(query1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: Then in the script - `$("#Cities").append($('<option></option>').val(Cities.City_id).text(Cities.City_name));`

Comment: thank you @@StephenMuecke ,i cleaned the controller code  ,please tell me  the difference between your way and what @MKA  suggested as both works

Comment: Its efficient! You already have collection of what you need. Converting  that to a Dictionary is just pointless extra overhead, as is then using `Serialize()` when the `Json()` method also does that (your serializing something that has already been serialized). And `ViewBag` properties are lost the moment your method returns so that too is pointless.

Comment: well i post the code before you show the controller code m agree to change all things suggested by @StephenMuecke you don't need that things

Comment: @StephenMuecke and what enables me to use dot operator with cites parameter in jquery foreach loop ?

Comment: @BRBHARDWAJ, You returning a collection of objects. Each object contains 2 properties (`City_id` and `City_name`). When you use `$.each(result, function (i, Cities)` - `Cities` is referring to the object in the collection, so `Cities.City_id` refers to the value of its `City_id` property. Suggest you also look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627421/better-way-to-load-2-dropdown-in-mvc/28640420#28640420)

Comment: wow @StephenMuecke commendable explanation for everything ,i wish i could have mark your comments as answer.  :)
thankyou

Comment: @Rohit Kumar answer actually addresses your original question so should be accepted :) (I'm just pointing out a better way of doing it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it a as below -

```
$.each(result, function (i, value) {
    var html='<option value="'+i+'">' + value + '</option>'
    $("#Cities").append(html);
});
```

Comment: actually i don't know  whether i should "key" and "value" to bind it ,so is  my json string suggesting that i should use "key' and "value" to bind data.

Comment: are you sure `Cities.val` and `Cities.key`?? seems like `undefined`

Comment: i don't know i copied it from a demo project ,wait i am posting my controller code

Comment: @BRBHARDWAJ see my jsfiddle link in comment on question

Comment: thanks Cerlin  i was in hurry while answering .. now it will work

Comment: wow ,you did it ,but please tell me that 'i' is holding numeric value from result?

Comment: yep i is the key of your json  which is numeric.@BRBHARDWAJ

Comment: thank you @rohit,can you please tell me the difference between @@stephens Muecke  way and what @@MKA suggested as both works –

Comment: @@MKA answer is just same as this solution on the other hand @@stephens's solution is doing things from backend .. go through as per your requirement

Comment: @RohitKumar what enables me to use dot operator with cites parameter in jquery foreach loop ,if i do it in stephens way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91355/discussion-between-br-bhardwaj-and-rohit-kumar).

Answer (score 1):

```
$.each(result, function (i, value) {
    var html='<option value="'+i+'">' + value + '</option>'
    $("#Cities").append(html);
});
```

this works but i have to use JSON.parse() as @MKA suggested i don't know why it works with Json.parse()

i am using stephens  answer btw.

Comment: Its because you serialize it twice (using the JavaScriptSerializer `.Serialize()` method and the Json() method so you then have to parse it back to Json in the client. If you removed `var json = jsonResult.Serialize(abc);` then you would not need `JSON.parse()` in the client.