# MVC4 jquery multiple dropdownlists

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui, dropdownlistfor

I am building my first mvc 4 application using Jquery and I am trying to use my selected item from my first dropdownlist to get a list of items in my second dropdownlist. And in my last dropdownlist i would like to use the selected item from the second dropdown for my last dropdownlist.

With my current code I can get data and return my partialView just with the week selection.

I want to give WeekChange method 4 parameters, selectedCompany, selectedProject, selectedSubProject and week to get my data. A button to call this method is a better idea because of the many selections.

Here is a part of my view (HoursReportViewModel):

```
     @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Week, Model._listOfWeeks, new { @onchange = "WeekChange(this.value)" })


    @Html.Label("Company:")
@Html.DataListForListBoxFor(model => model.selectedCompany.Name, Model._companies, new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "class", "form-control" } })
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.selectedCompany);


@Html.Label("Project:")
@Html.DataListForListBoxFor(model => model.selectedProject.Name, Model._projects, new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "class", "form-control" } })
  @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.selectedProject);


@Html.Label("SubProject:")
@Html.DataListForListBoxFor(model => model.selectedSubProject.Name, Model._subProjects, new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "class", "form-control" } })
  @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.selectedSubProject);


@Html.Partial("~/Views/UrenOverzicht/UrenPartial.cshtml", Model);
```

scripts:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

    function WeekChange(value) {
        var week = parseInt(value);
        var year = @Model.Year;
        $('#Week').val(week);

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("HoursReportPartial", "HoursReport")',
            data: 'jaar=' + jaar + '&week=' + week,
            type: 'get',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                $('.rightReportPartial').html(data);
            }
        });
    }



</script>
```

My ViewModel:

```
    public int Week { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> _listOfWeeks { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> _companies { get; set; }
    public Company selectedCompany { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> _projects { get; set; }
    public Project selectedProject { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> _subProjects { get; set; }
    public Subproject selectedSubProject { get; set; }
```

And finally my method in the controller:

```
        [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult HoursReportPartial(int year, int week)
    {
        var hoursViewModel = GetHoursReportViewModel(year, week);
        return PartialView("~/Views/HoursReport/HoursPartial.cshtml", hoursViewModel);
    }
```

Comment: What is `DataListForListBoxFor()`? - thats not part of MVC. Suggest you look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627421/better-way-to-load-2-dropdown-in-mvc/28640420#28640420) and [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JofdB8) for a working example of cascading dropdownlists

Comment: @StephenMuecke The DataListForListBox returns MvcHtmlString. This is a html helper which I a have implemented. The DotNetFiddle example is very nice thanks for that! I tried to change the code of it so that this wil work for me too but I could not make it work :( I am still troubleshooting...

Comment: @StephenMuecke I am trying to get this work in my project but it is not working as I expect. With my code, I get just the first dropdown filled in, when selecting an item from this dropdown, the second dropdown is not loaded. Please see my DotNetFiddle with my code [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/t7yYoD) . I can't get my code run in dotnetFiddle because of my unitOfWork and other components that I am using. I hope to hear from you.

Comment: There is no point creating a DotNetFiddle that refers to database access components :) There is no way I can really help because I have no idea what your`UnitOfWork` class is doing or what its is returning. All you can do is debug the code in your project.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I solved my problem using the example from DotNetFiddle. Thank you very much!