# Ajax form with different actions in ASP MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-ajax

In ASP.NET MVC I have the following input form (simplified):

```
<div id="ajaxtarget">
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SubmitForm", "Home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "ajaxtarget" }))
{
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.PostalCode, Model.PostalCodeItemList, new { @name = "PostalCodeId" , @id="PostalCodeId" })

        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.StreetCode)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.StreetCode, Model.StreetItemList, new {  @id="StreetCodeId" })

        ...
        <input type="submit" value="@Global.Execute" id="btnSubmit" />
}
</div>
```

When the user selects something from the first dropdownlist, the second dropdownlist should be populated via AJAX. I can send 'call' my controller via javascript to update my view:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#PostalCodeId').on('change', function () {
            $(this).parents('form').submit();
        });
    });
```

My problem is that my form has a lot of different controls that trigger some action I need to handle in my controller, so I'm looking for a way to add some extra parameters when I submit my form.

Right now I found a solution where I add an extra field in my model and in my form that I populate in javascript depending on which control fires the script. `@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ChosenControllerAction, new { id = "ChosenAction" })` In my controller I can return a view or action based on this value:

```
    public ActionResult SubmitForm(MyModel model) 
    {
        if (model.ChosenControllerAction == "PopulateStreetCodes")
        {
          ...
        }
```

I'm sure there must be a different/better way to archieve what I want to do. What's the right way to return the correct ActionResults in a complex *self updating* ajax form?

Comment: _the second dropdownlist should be populated via AJAX_?? Your not doing that at all - your script just submits the form. What is it that you really want to do?

Comment: Exactly, I am submitting the form via ajax and based on the selection in the first dropdownlist my ajaxtarget will be refreshed and the values in my model for the second list are updated. In reality the form is more complex than this though. I said what I really want to do:  "I'm looking for a way to add some extra parameters when I submit my form."

Comment: But you have said in your question that the _second dropdownlist should be populated via AJAX_ based on the selection of the first - i.e. cascading dropdownlists. You don't submit a form to do that. Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627421/better-way-to-load-2-dropdown-in-mvc/28640420#28640420) and [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/) for an example

Comment: That's a simplified example. I chose the route of an AJAX form that updates the DIV that contains my form and I'd prefer this way if possible...

Comment: No problem (if your happy with poor performance)

Comment: And your code is not doing and ajax - its just a piece of javascript which calls `('form').submit();` whicjh is a normal submit (no different that what happens when you click a submit button)

Comment: Isn't submitting an AJAX form "doing any ajax"? It looks like it anyway since (only) my `<div id="ajaxtarget">` is being updated without a full page refresh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way to do that is to create one method for each action you want to do in your controller. And you should have one javascript code for each of these actions.

Example :

Controller

```
public ActionResult PopulateFirstDropdown(MyModel model)
{
    // Return the new values for your first dropdownlist
    // Or the partial view
}

public ActionResult PopulateSecondDropdown(MyModel model)
{
    // Return the new values for your second dropdownlist
    // Or the partial view
}

public ActionResult SubmitForm(MyModel model)
{
    // Save the form
}
```

Javascript :

```
$('#FirstField').on('change', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/YourController/PopulateFirstDropdown",
        type: "POST",
        data:  $(this).closest('form').serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            // Use data to refresh dropdownlist
            // or refresh the content of the partial view
        },
    });
});

$('#OtherField').on('change', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/YourController/PopulateSecondDropdown",
        type: "POST",
        data:  $(this).closest('form').serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            // Use data to refresh dropdownlist
            // or refresh the content of the partial view
        },
    });
});
```

Let me know if my answer is not clear enough.

Comment: I don't understand the javascript code. I suppose `success: function (data)` should fire the controller's ActionResult as in the url `MyController/Action` ?  The problem is, it doesn't... I've put a breakpoint in my controller's method to be sure, but I doesn't get there.

Comment: The ajax method sends an asynchronous request to the server, at the url that you passed in parameter. The success parameter represent a function that will be executed when the request returns without problem. The "data" parameter will contains the data returned by the server (What your controller method returns). You can see an AJAX tutorial here : [link](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/jquery-ajax-methods/)