# $.getJSON (url) not moving to the controller

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing my application in my MVC. I am using cascading dropdown list in my application. On selecting one i have 2 dropdown one is location and another one is employee. While selecting a location particular employee should be fetched in employee dropdown. I am using json result to retrieve the employee.

My code is

View Page

```
@Html.DropDownList("location", ViewBag.Location as SelectList, "Select the Location", new { id = "location" })

<div id=" employeediv" style="width:600px; height:50px">
    <div style="float:left">
        <label> Employee:</label>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left:220px">
        <select id="Employee" name="employee" style="width:150px"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
@section scripts{
   <script type="text/javascript">

    $('#location').change(function () {
            @*var url = '@Url.Action("Employe", "Appt")';*@
           //var url = "/Appt/Employee/"
           debugger;
           $.getJSON('/Appt/Employee/' + $('#location').val(), function (data) {

               var item = '<option> Any </option>';
               $.each(data, function (i, employee) {

                   item += "<option value ='" + employee.Value + "'>" + employee.Text +
                       "</option>";


               });

               $("#employee").html(items);

           });




       });

</script>

}
```

Controller Code

```
public ActionResult CalendarView(int? id, int? CustomerUserid)
        {
            tblBusinessCategory bc = new tblBusinessCategory();

          ViewBag.Location = new SelectList(from s in db.tblBusinessLocations
                                            where s.BusinessID == id
                                            join loc in db.tblLocations
                                                on s.LocID equals loc.LocationId
                                            select loc.LocationName);
         return View();
}


  public JsonResult Employee(int id)
        {

            SYTEntities db = new SYTEntities();
            var emp = from s in db.Employees
                      where s.LocationId == id 
                      select s;
            return Json(new SelectList(emp.ToArray(), "EmpId", "EmpName"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

My problem is While changing the location url is not redirecting to the controller and it is came out from its scope 
**$.getJSON('/Appt/Employee/' + $('#location').val(), function**

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean _it is came out from its scope_? I also recommend you study this [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JofdB8) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627421/better-way-to-load-2-dropdown-in-mvc/28640420#28640420)

Comment: And since you `location` dropdownlist seems to be generating options with a `value` attribute that is the value of property `LocationName` its unlikely to be able to bind to a parameter which is `int id`

Comment: it is not redirecting to the corresponding controller

Comment: What error are you getting in the browser console. No doubt a 500 Internal Server Error because your passing the the value of a `LocationName` property to a method expecting typeof `int` as I previously noted

Comment: Didnt get any error in console. It is not displaying anything in employee dropdown

Comment: How do you expect the value of `loc.LocationName` to bind to an `int`? And study the links I gave you. Sorry to be harsh but your code is awful.

Comment: ok thanks for your help :)