# Make select box change values when another value is selected from another select box

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I want my select box to change depending which option I choose in the first select, and I want to hide the values that are not from that option/

My HTML here:

```
<select id="localidad">
            @foreach (ja_era.Models.Localidades localidad in ViewBag.localidades)
            {
                <option value="@localidad.Id">@localidad.Zona</option>
            }
        </select>
        <select name="Localidad" id="barrio">
            @foreach (ja_era.Models.Barrios barrio in ViewBag.barrios)
            {
                <option class="@barrio.Localidad" value="@barrio.Id">@barrio.Barrio</option>
            }
        </select>
```

The Localidad select has 4 options and bring the countries, then I have the second select that brings the cities all in one select box. Which ones are well defined in my database.

[image]

[image]

You can see here that "Barrios" has the column localidad where I insert the localidad id

I have tried some js code but can't figure it out how to make it work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#localidad').change(function () {
    });
})
```

Comment: Search for MVC Cascading DropDownLists. Refer [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627421/better-way-to-load-2-dropdown-in-mvc/28640420#28640420)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to get the value of the selected option of the first dropdown, send it to your an action method and let it return the data for the second dropdown in json format. Then you will go through the items in the JSON array and build the markup for the options in the second dropdown.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#localidad').change(function () {
     var v = $(this).val();  
     var urlToGetData="@Url.Action("GetBarrios","Home")";

     var items="";
     $.getJSON(urlToGetData+"?id="+v,function(a,item){
       items+="<option value='"+item.Value+"'>"+item.Text+"</option>";
     })
     $("#barrio").html(items);
  });
})
```

Assuming you have `GetBarrios` action method like this

```
public ActionResult GetBarrios(int id)
{
   var items=db.Barrios.Where(s=>s.Localidad==id)
            .Select(s=> new SelectListItem { 
                                             Value=s.Id.ToString(),
                                             Text = s.Barrio
                                           }).ToList();
   return Json(items,JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);
}
```