# C# MVC Not updating Html.DropDownListFor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I require 3 dropdown lists on my page. They will work as follows:

A user must select from the first dropdown to see the list in the second dropdown. The second and third work in the same way.

Index method fills the first dropdownlist:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.ClientDropdownList = GetClientsDropDown();
        return View();
    }
```

After a user selects any item from the first dropdown:

```
$(function () {
    $('#clientDropdown').change(function () {
        var val = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/Home/GetClientsProjectsDropDown',
            data: { 'data': val },
            success: function (data) {
            },
            error: function (data) {
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Which forwards to:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetClientsProjectsDropDown(string data)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
            {
                var result = new List<SelectListItem>();
                var clientProjects = _clientService.GetClientsProjects(Int32.Parse(data));
                foreach (var proj in clientProjects)
                {
                    var item = new SelectListItem()
                    {
                        Value = proj.ProjectID.ToString(),
                        Text = proj.ProjectName
                    };
                    result.Add(item);
                }
                TempData["ProjectDropdownList"] = result;
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return PartialView();
        }
```

Here is index.cshtml:

```
<div style="display: inline-flex; text-align: center;">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Client, ViewBag.ClientDropdownList as List<SelectListItem>, "Clients", new { @id = "clientDropdown", @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
                <div id="projectDropdown" class="dropdown" style="margin-left: 10px;">
                    @if (TempData["ProjectDropdownList"] != null)
                    {
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Project, TempData["ProjectDropdownList"] as List<SelectListItem>, "Projects", new { @id = "projectDropdown", @class = "form-control" })
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Project, new List<SelectListItem>(), "Projects", new { @id = "projectDropdown", @class = "form-control" })
                    }
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown" style="margin-left: 10px;">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Task, new List<SelectListItem>(), "Tasks", new { @id = "taskDropdown", @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

Why is the second dropdown not being updated?

Comment: How do you expect your dropdown updated, if your success function callback is empty? It's also overall not the best approach to make "GET" action a "POST" + return Partial View, not raw data.

Comment: can You help me what should I do now?

Comment: Better to return Json object rather than PartialView. Then your success method would loop through returned data and build up DDL.

Comment: Not a lot of you code makes any sense. You have a `return RedirectToAction("Index");` in your method and ajax calls DO NOT redirect (the whole point of ajax is to stay on the same page). And then you ont even do anything with the data you return in the success callback. Suggest you refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627421/better-way-to-load-2-dropdown-in-mvc/28640420#28640420) and [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym) to understand how to implement cascading dropdownlists

Comment: You were totally right, thank you guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your success callback is empty:

```
 success: function (data) {
    },
```

The data argument should have the partial HTML from the controller.  You should add this HTML to the DOM.  For example,

```
    success: function (data) {
         $('#dropdown2Wrapper').add(data);
    },
```

Obviously, you will need to create a div with the id "dropdown2Wrapper" or change this reference to the appropriate jQuery selector.