# How to manually set property value in Ajax.BeginForm()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel, ajax.beginform

I have shared the view and the viewmodel below. I populated an indented select list (with `optgroup`) by using `foreach` loop instead of using some `@Html` helper. However, I do not know how to assign the selected value from the list to a specific property of the `CreateMainEntryViewModel`. More specifically, I need to set `DiscussionWallId`, and `TimeFrameId` property values based on the selection made in the dropdownlist when the form is submitted with. In this task I am using `Ajax.BeginForm()` :

```
@model EcholuMvc.Models.CreateMainEntryViewModel
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateMainEntry", "MainEntry", new AjaxOptions
{     
    UpdateTargetId = "div_MainEntries",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
}))
{       

     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title, new { placeholder = "Write a brief title...", @class = "form-control input-lg" })

     @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Content, new { placeholder = "Type your entry here...", @class = "form-control mainEntryField" })

     <label for="drp_DiscussionWallListForNewMainEntry" style="text-align:right" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Choose the Discussion Wall:</label>

     <select id="drp_DWListForNewMainEntry" class="form-control">
     @{
          foreach (DiscussionWall dw in Model.DiscussionWalls)
          {
               <optgroup label="@dw.WallTitle">
               foreach (TimeFrame tf in dw.TimeFrames)
               {
                  <option data-dw="@dw.WallId" data-tf="@tf.TimeFrameId">@tf.TimeFrameName</option>
               }              
                </optgroup>
         }
     }
     </select>

    <button type="submit" id="btn_SubmitNewPost">Post</button>                           

}
```

This is the viewmodel:

```
public class CreateMainEntryViewModel
{

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Content { get; set; }

    public Boolean IsAnonymous { get; set; }

    public int DiscussionWallId { get; set; }

    public int TimeFrameId { get; set; }

    public CreateMainEntryViewModel(List<DiscussionWall> walls)
    {
        DiscussionWalls = walls;
    }

    public List< DiscussionWall> DiscussionWalls { get; set; }
}
```

I appreciate any help!

Comment: You need to give the `<select>` element a `name` attribute which matches the property name (but why not just use the html helper?)

Comment: @StephenMuecke can you please elaborate more? I do not think it is possible to group and indent list items with the html helper.

Comment: Depends which version of MVC. If you using MVC-5 then grouping is supported.

Comment: @StephenMuecke ohh I see, thanks for this information. However, I believe in my case manually creating the list is better (sorry I have not shared all the details to keep it the code short). If I want to keep it as it is, then how can I resolve the main issue?

Comment: As I noted in the first comment - set the `name` attribute. (and just to clarify, its MVC-5.2 that would be needed to do this out of the box)

Comment: @StephenMuecke you may see in the OP that each `option` item has `data-dw` and `data-tf` attributes. I need to read these attribute values and assign them to DiscussionWallId and TimeFrameId properties of the viewmodel, repectively. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: I have no idea what thos attributes are for, but if you want an option to be selected when the view is first generated, then you need to set the `selected="selected"` attribute of the relavant option (and you need to set the `name` attribute if you want to submit the selected value). You cannot set `DiscussionWallId` and `TimeFrameId` using those attributes unless you were to add hidden inputs for them and use javascript to handle the `.change()` event and update the `value` of the hidden inputs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105466/discussion-between-renakre-and-stephen-muecke).

Comment: @renakre good to see you again. And taking into account that you want to build the select list this way, You can acheive your requirement if you can use jquery. I guees you would be already using it. Let me know. Also for the slect list to map to your ViewModel after submitting the form just set the name attribute of the select element same as the property you want to map it into

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To directly answer your question, you need to include a hidden input for the `DiscussionWallId` property, add a `name` attribute for the `<select>` element and `value` attributes for its `<option>` elements, and use javascript/jquery to update the value of the hidden input based on the selected option.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DiscussionWallId) // add
<select name="TimeFrameId" id="TimeFrameId" class="form-control"> // add name attribute
@{
  foreach (DiscussionWall dw in Model.DiscussionWalls)
  {
    <optgroup label="@dw.WallTitle">
      foreach (TimeFrame tf in dw.TimeFrames)
      {
        <option data-dw="@dw.WallId" value="@tf.TimeFrameId">@tf.TimeFrameName</option> // modify
      }              
  </optgroup>
}
</select>
```

and to update the value of the hidden input

```
$('#TimeFrameId').change(function() {
    var dw = $(this).children('option:selected).data('dw');
    $('#DiscussionWallId').val(dw);
});
```

Both the `DiscussionWallId` and `TimeFrameId` properties will now be bound when you submit the form.

However adding the hidden input (and your `data-dw` attributes) is unnecessary (and a malicious user could easily change the value of the hidden input, potentially causing your app to fail). If for any reason you need the `DiscussionWallId` property associated with the selected `TimeFrame`, then you should be getting that value from the repository based on the value of `TimeFrameId`.

There are also many other reasons why this is a poor design including you are not getting strongly typed 2-way model binding and you cannot use the built in client side validation features.

If you using MVC-5.2, then you can use the `Group` property of [SelectListItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlistitem(v=vs.118).aspx), or the overloads of [SelectList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist.selectlist(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.SelectList.) that accepts a `dataGroupField` value to generate an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` that supports grouped options in the view and then simply use the strongly typed `@Html.DropDownListFor()` helper. However this is really only suitable if you have a few `DiscussionWalls` objects, and each one contains only a few `TimeFrame` objects. If not, then you should be implementing cascading dropdownlists. For an example, refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627421/better-way-to-load-2-dropdown-in-mvc/28640420#28640420) and [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym).

Comment: Do you think its fine to include Jquery in your solution when there is no tag for Jquery?? No offence just taking guide. I consider you ass a role model

Comment: Because OP is using `Ajax.BeginForm()` so it must be using jquery :) (and you can also read the comments in chat)

Comment: Ya true.. Thanks, I asked it beacause previously I got a downvote for providing solution in jquery when there was no tag for it. But I see its completely valid here.

Comment: @Reddy, I assume it was a case that the user tagged it `javascript` (and not `jquery`). In this case there were neither tags (but either javascript or jquery would be required to handle the client side event)

Comment: Ya I agree. You rock