# Binding from table based on radio button selected value

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am newbie to MVC. I have 2 tables namely tb_RepDetails and tb_AgentDetails.In View, the user can select either "Representative" or "Agent" through Radio button, So based on the User selection, either "RepId" or "AgentId" will bind on the dropdownlist.I want to pass the selected "Id" (VARCHAR) as Parameter in the Stored Procedure.

```html
<tr>
    <td><b>Mediator</b> </td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="Mediator" id="Rep1" value="Representative" style="width:5%" checked="checked" />REPRESENTATIVE
        <input type="radio" name="Mediator" id="Agent1" value="Agent" style="width:5%" />AGENT
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><b>Identificaton Number</b> </td>
   <td>:</td>
   <td>
       @Html.DropDownList("EmpNo", new SelectList(ViewBag.Emp), "select", new { required = "required", style = "height:28px", onchange = "detailsempt()" })<b style="color: red;">*</b> <span id="IDddl"></span>
   </td>
 </tr>
```

```js
<script>
    function detailsempt() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetEmpDetails", "Advertiser")',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { Usr: $("#EmpNo").val() },
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#MedDetails").val(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Are you wanting to change the options in the dropdownlist based on the value of the selected radio button?

Comment: Yes. As in the picture, If the user select "Agent", then the Agent IDs are bind from the table "tb_AgentDetails". The Javascipt i wrote for display the Emp Name, Designation in textbox based on selection from dropdownlist

Comment: Then you need to handle the `.change()` event of the radio buttons and use ajax to calls a controller method (passing the value of the selected button) which returns the data for building the options.

Comment: Suggest you look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627421/better-way-to-load-2-dropdown-in-mvc/28640420#28640420) - its for cascading dropdownlists, where as your 'first' element is a set of radio buttons, but its the same principal.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. how i pass the value of the selected button (In my View currently both buttons are select)

Comment: `$('input[type="radio"]:checked').val()` will return the value of the selected button (although it would be better to give them a class name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the guidelines given by Stepen Muecke and others i did this task. I give the code so that it will help for others for future reference.Welcome If anyone can simply this.

```
     <tr>
            <td><b>Payment Method</b> </td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td>
                @foreach (var pay in ViewBag.RadioPayList)
                {
                    <input type="radio" name="Payment" style="width:5%" value="@pay" required onclick="selectPayMode(this)" />@pay
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Mediator</b> </td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td>
                @foreach (var i in ViewBag.RadioList)
                {
                    <input type="radio" name="Mediator" style="width:5%" value="@i" required onclick="selectEmpid(this)" />@i
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
```

JQuery:

```
     <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
       //First time according the checked radio button to populate ddl
       RadioLoadData();
       $("input[name='Mediator']").change(function () {
           //reload dropdownlist
           RadioLoadData();
       })
   });

   function RadioLoadData() {
       $("input[name='Mediator']").each(function () {
           if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
               var value = $(this).val();
               var ddlId = $("#ddlEmpNo");
               $.ajax({
                   type: "Post",
                   url: '@Url.Action("GetEmpId", "Advertiser")',
                    data: '{value: "' + value + '"}',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        ddlId.html("");
                        //var selectvalue = "";
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            ddlId.append($('<option></option>').val(data[i].Value).html(data[i].Text));
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert('Failed to retrieve ID Numbers');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
     public JsonResult GetEmpId(string value)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        string connstr1 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connstr1);
        con.Open();
        List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();
        if (value == "AGENT")
        {
            // query the tb_AgentDetails table and get values.
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select AgentId from tb_AgentDetails", con);
            using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd1.ExecuteReader())
            {
                List<string> result = new List<string>();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    string EmpId = rdr["AgentId"].ToString();
                    result.Add(EmpId);
                }
                rdr.Close();

                for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
                {
                    list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = result[i].ToString(), Value = result[i].ToString() });
                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        if (value == "REPRESENTATIVE")
        {
            //query the tb_RepDetails table and get values.
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select RepId from tb_RepDetails", con);
            using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd1.ExecuteReader())
            {
                   List<string> result = new List<string>();
                   while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        string EmpId = rdr["RepId"].ToString();
                        result.Add(EmpId);
                    }
                   rdr.Close();

                   for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
                   {
                       list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = result[i].ToString(), Value = result[i].ToString() });
                   }
                   con.Close();
             }
        }
      return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```