# Cascading Dropdown List Updating Database Call

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I currently have a need to create a cascading drop down list

```
    <td>@Html.LabelFor(u => u.States)</td>
    <td>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.State, new SelectList(Model.States), new { style = "height:27px;border: 1px solid grey;", @id = "StateSelected" })                                                      
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.States)
         @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CustomerNumber)
    </td>                
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>@Html.LabelFor(u => u.ShipToCode)</td>
    <td>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ShipToCode, new SelectList(Model.Sites, "Code", "Address"), new { style = "height:27px;border: 1px solid grey;" })                                                      
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Sites)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CustomerNumber)
    </td>                
</tr>
```

Selection of the first states, will allow a more refined address based on states selected

The current states are loaded from the controller

```
private SitesModel GetDistinctStates(SitesModel model)
{
    model.States = new List<string>();
    using (NAVLIVEEntities entities = new NAVLIVEEntities())
    {
        try
        {
            List<GetServiceDeliveryAddress_Result> Addresses = entities.GetServiceDeliveryAddress(model.CustomerNumber).ToList();
            IEnumerable<string> Addresses_Unique = Addresses.Select(x => x.County).Distinct();
            List<string> Address_Unique_List = Addresses_Unique.ToList();
            model.States.Add("ALL STATES");
            foreach (string uniqueStates in Address_Unique_List)
            {
                model.States.Add(uniqueStates);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ///Do nothing
        }
    }
    return model;
}

private SitesModel GetSiteAddresses(SitesModel model, string state)
{
    model.Sites = new List<SitesModel.SiteAddresses>();
    using (NAVLIVEEntities entities = new NAVLIVEEntities())
    {
        try
        {
            List<GetServiceDeliveryAddress_Result> Addresses = entities.GetServiceDeliveryAddress(model.CustomerNumber).ToList();
            foreach (var site in Addresses)
            {
                SitesModel.SiteAddresses address = new SitesModel.SiteAddresses();
                address.Code = site.Code;
                address.Address = site.Address + " " + site.Address_2 + ", " + site.City + " " + site.County + " " + site.Post_Code;
                model.Sites.Add(address);
            }
        }
    catch
    {

    }
    return model;
}
```

The first controller will list the distinct states from the entity.

The second controller will aim to display the list based on the states selected of the first.

There are multiple ways of implementation out there but I can't seem to wrap my head around the ways to do it this way.

EDIT

In my javascript, as suggested I've done

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var localityUrl = '@Url.Action("FetchSites")';
    var localities = $('#FetchSites');
    $('#SelectedState').change(function () {
        var txt = $(this).val();
        alert(txt);
        $.getJSON(localityUrl, { model: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)), State: $(this).val() }, function (data) {
            if (!data) {
                return;
            }
            localities.append($('<option></option>').val('').text('Please select'));
            $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                localities.append($('<option></option>').val(item.Value).text(item.Text));
            });
        });
    })
</Script>
```

And doing this on the controller

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult FetchSites(SitesModel model, string State)
    {
        var data = model.Sites.Where(l => l.State == State).Select(l => l.Address);

        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

However, i don't seem to be passing the model correctly so that the data's passed for filtering. Any suggestions?

EDIT 2: Site population

```
private SitesModel GetSiteAddresses(SitesModel model)
    {
        model.Sites = new List<SitesModel.SiteAddresses>();
        using (NAVLIVEEntities entities = new NAVLIVEEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                List<GetServiceDeliveryAddress_Result> Addresses = entities.GetServiceDeliveryAddress(model.CustomerNumber).ToList();

                foreach (var site in Addresses)
                {
                    SitesModel.SiteAddresses address = new SitesModel.SiteAddresses();
                    address.Code = site.Code;
                    address.Address = site.Address + " " + site.Address_2 + ", " + site.City + " " + site.County + " " + site.Post_Code;
                    address.State = site.County;
                    model.Sites.Add(address);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
        return model;
    }
```

Comment: What part are you struggling with? (and you have so much unnecesary code here - your `GetDistinctStates()` code can be reduced down to one or 2 lines). Suggest you refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym) for an example of cascading dropdownlists

Comment: Hi Stephen, I'm struggling to repopulate the second dropdown list on the event of change for the first drop down list. I'm struggling massively due to my extremely limited knowledge on javascript and json in general. Any pointers will be really appreciated. I'll read through the link in the mean time but if you do have any inputs, it'll be great. Also, for GetDistinctStates, any suggestions to drop down the lines?

Comment: Look at the fiddle I linked to. Also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627421/better-way-to-load-2-dropdown-in-mvc/28640420#28640420)

Comment: Stephen, ive spent sometime going through it but im still having massive issues. Mind providing some input to the edit ive put in place?

Comment: Why on earth does your `FetchSites()` method have parameters `SitesModel model` and `string models`? - Remove them. And just pass `{ State: $(this).val() }`

Comment: oh boy that was disastrous. I've removed the string models (was supposed to be testing something). However, if I remove SitesModel model, I won't be able to display the second list containing the Sites based on the State selected. The Sites population is put on edit note above.

Comment: I have no idea what you think `model: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode())` would do (other than pass `null` to the method). You pass the selected state to the method and query you databaseto get the sites based on that selected site. Go back and study the fiddle.

Comment: Ill fiddle around with it tad more. Sorry to raise your ire if anything. I was genuinely having issues behind the concept. It was meant to be passed as `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)) ` . I thought passing model will be best because the database prompt contains existing variables to be passed through such as Customernumber.

Comment: If its now `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))`, then that's just pointless - it would be sending back the original unchanged model that you just sent to the client. Not clear why you would need the whole model and you model should definitely not contain a collection for sites. You call the database to get the sites based on the selected State.