# Dynamically populate a DropdownList based on another DropDownList's selection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to be able to populate a DropDownList based on the selection of a prior DropDownList.

I noticed there are allot of similar topics on SO, unfortunately, I need to do this with out using an AJAX call and needs to be done in MVC5 without doing a postback (If Possible).

1. Is this even possible?
2. Where do I begin? Is/Are there any examples I can go off of?

Comment: Short answer is no, its not possible. If you do not want to use javascript/ajax, then you will need to submit a form to post back the value of the 1st dropdownlist, then redirect or return the view with the data populated for the 2nd dropdownlist

Comment: OK,.. Kinda figured. Was hoping I could get away with doing this on the fly with out AJAX.

Comment: Although if you are OK using javascript, you could send all the data for 2nd dropdownlist and store it in a javascript array, and then handle the change event of the 1st dropdownlist to populate the 2nd.

Comment: {facepalm} forgot about that option. That would work instead of creating an API for this instance. Thank you.

Comment: Refer the last option of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627421/better-way-to-load-2-dropdown-in-mvc/28640420#28640420) for an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually it is possible to do it without AJAX but would still require some Javascript:

Both first and second dropdowns should have all the available options prerenderd. For each option on the second dropdown specify for what value of the first dropdown the option should be visible. For example:

```
<select id="firstDd">
   <option value="car">Cars</option>
   <option value="plane">Planes</option>
</select >


<select id="secondDd">
   <option value="ferrari" data-display-on="car">Ferrari</option>
   <option value="bugatti" data-display-on="car">Bugatti</option>
   <option value="747" data-display-on="plane">Boeing 747</option>
   <option value="757" data-display-on="plane">Boeing 757</option>
</select >
```

Now with some simple javascript you can toggle visibility of second dropdown options based on the value of first one:

```
$('#firstDd').change(function(){
  var value = $(this).val();
  if(value)
  {
    var $secondDd = $('#secondDd');
    var $selectedOption = $('option:selected', $(this));
    $('option', $secondDd).hide();
    $('option[data-display-on="'+value+'"]',$secondDd).show();    
  }
  $($secondDd).val(null);
})

$('#firstDd').change();
```

Here is [working JSFiDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/v81a000v/4/) that demonstrates this approach