# Combobox Selection event MVC 4

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

Is it possible to have dynamic combobox values based on value of another combobox?

I have view with 2 combo boxes, both with static values (no need for db call to load them)

Combobox 1 Values:

1. People
2. Animals

If the user select the first option, the values of the second combobox should be

1. Man
2. Woman

If the user select the second option, the values of the second comboBox should be

1. Cat
2. Dog

In my view model i have

```
public string InputType{ get; set; }
    public IList<SelectListItem> TypeList
    {
        get
        {
            var optionList = new List<SelectListItem>();
            optionList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "People", Value = "P" });
            optionList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Animal", Value = "A" });
            return optionList;
        }

    }

    public string People { get; set; }
    public IList<SelectListItem> PeopleList
    {
        get
        {
            var optionList = new List<SelectListItem>();
            optionList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Man", Value = "Man" });
            optionList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Woman", Value = "Woman" });
            return optionList;
        }

    }

    public string Animal { get; set; }
    public IList<SelectListItem> AnimalList
    {
        get
        {
            var optionList = new List<SelectListItem>();
            optionList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Cat", Value = "Cat" });
            optionList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Dog", Value = "Dog" });
            return optionList;
        }

    }
```

> View

```
  <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputSmall" class="col-xs-2 control-label">@Consts.Type</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.InputType, Model.TypeList, new { @class = "form-control input-sm" })
                        </div>

                    </div>
```

how can i:

1. select event that load the second combobox?
2. Or use jquery to perform this task?

Comment: you have to use jquery and send ajax call on selection change to populate other combo box

Comment: Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627421/better-way-to-load-2-dropdown-in-mvc/28640420#28640420) for some examples. In you case, you do not need ajax, but you will need javascript/jquery

Comment: Answer can be found in this post
[Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627421/better-way-to-load-2-dropdown-in-mvc/28640420#28640420)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Great answer! I added **please select** to the first combobox so that nothing is selected at the beginning and all works fine. however, when i re-select **please select** the second combobox is not refreshed, the event is not firing? i want when i select **Please Select** the cities combo box be empty

Comment: Not sure which of the options your using in that answer (I assume the last one where your not using ajax). In the `.change()` function, you can first call `cities.empty()`, to remove all options, followed by `if(!$(this).val()) { return; }` which will exit the function if you have selected "please select"

Comment: Refer also [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym) for a working example (in that case using ajax to call server methods for populating the options)