# populate tow dropdown lists in mv one after another

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new in mvc5,i created one view with two dropdown lists(A,B) and I bind it using EF.
I want to fill the second dropdown list (B) after the page load finish then take the first item from dropdown list (A) and bind the second one depend on that value, I did this in aspx form but I couldn't get in mvc.if there is any solution without using jquery??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [better way to load 2 dropdown in mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627421/better-way-to-load-2-dropdown-in-mvc)

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, which will display two ddls.  First values 1-4, second values 5-8.  When you select an item from the first list, it adds it to the second list.

Controller:

```
public class ModelForDropDowns
{
    public IList<SelectListItem> dropDwownOneList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    public IList<SelectListItem> dropDwownTwoList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    public string selectedDDL1Item { get; set; }
    public string selectedDDL2Item { get; set; }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index27(ModelForDropDowns m)
    {
        ModelGetDDL(m);

        //add selected item from list1 to list2
        m.dropDwownTwoList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = m.selectedDDL1Item, Value = m.selectedDDL1Item });
        return View(m);
    }

    public ActionResult Index27()
    {
        ModelForDropDowns mfd = new ModelForDropDowns();
        ModelGetDDL(mfd);

        return View(mfd);
    }

    void ModelGetDDL(ModelForDropDowns mfd)
    {
        SelectListItem sli1 = new SelectListItem { Text = "t1", Value = "v1" };
        SelectListItem sli2 = new SelectListItem { Text = "t2", Value = "v2" };
        SelectListItem sli3 = new SelectListItem { Text = "t3", Value = "v3" };
        SelectListItem sli4 = new SelectListItem { Text = "t4", Value = "v4" };
        SelectListItem sli5 = new SelectListItem { Text = "t5", Value = "v5" };
        SelectListItem sli6 = new SelectListItem { Text = "t6", Value = "v6" };
        SelectListItem sli7 = new SelectListItem { Text = "t7", Value = "v7" };
        SelectListItem sli8 = new SelectListItem { Text = "t8", Value = "v8" };
        mfd.dropDwownOneList.Add(sli1);
        mfd.dropDwownOneList.Add(sli2);
        mfd.dropDwownOneList.Add(sli3);
        mfd.dropDwownOneList.Add(sli4);
        mfd.dropDwownTwoList.Add(sli5);
        mfd.dropDwownTwoList.Add(sli6);
        mfd.dropDwownTwoList.Add(sli7);
        mfd.dropDwownTwoList.Add(sli8);
    }
```

View:

```
@model Testy20161006.Controllers.ModelForDropDowns
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index27</title>
    @*You can add this auto post*@
    @*<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $("#list1DDL").change(function () {
                    $("#form1").submit();
                })
            })
        </script>*@
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Index27", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form1" }))
        {
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.LabelFor(r => r.dropDwownOneList)</td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.selectedDDL1Item,
                            new SelectList(Model.dropDwownOneList, "Value", "Text"),
                            new { id = "list1DDL" })
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.LabelFor(r => r.dropDwownTwoList)</td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.selectedDDL2Item,
                            new SelectList(Model.dropDwownTwoList, "Value", "Text"))
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" id="btn1" />
        }
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```