# How can I populate and re-populate sub-fields without firing another AJAX call?

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a cascading dropdown which works perfectly thus far. Now I need to populate the text boxes as depicted below.

[image: Cascading Dropdowns]

[image: Secondary text fields based on Select Species Dropdown]

**AJAX Code**

```
   $('#CommonHerpsDropdown').change(function () {
        $('#SpeciesDropdown').empty();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetGenericSpeciesByCommonId")',
            datatype: "Json",
            data: { cAnimalId: $('#CommonHerpsDropdown').val() },
            success: function (genericSpecies) {
                $.each(genericSpecies, function (index, value) {
                    $('#SpeciesDropdown').append('<option value="' + value.SpeciesId + '">' + value.StandardName + '</option>');
                    $('#ScientificClass').val(value.ScientificClassification);
                    $('#ScientificOrder').val(value.ScientificOrder);
                    $('#ScientificFamily').val(value.ScientificFamily);
                    $('#ScientificGenus').val(value.ScientificGenus);
                    $('#ScientificSpecies').val(value.ScientificSpecies);
                });
            }
        });

    });
```

**MVC Controller Json Method**

```
 public JsonResult GetGenericSpeciesByCommonId(int cAnimalId)
        {
            //Lets get the species data based on CommonHerpID.
            var genericSpecies = (from x in _context.ReptileSpeciesList 
                                 where x.CommonHerpId == @cAnimalId 
                                 select x).OrderBy(x => x.StandardName);   
            return Json(genericSpecies);
        }
```

My question is how can I setup the classification and order fields to populate/repopulate when the species selection changes without using another call to the db table.

Comment: What is the issue with the current code? You seem to be populating the text box too

Comment: The code works. But I was trying to see if there was a way to avoid $('#SpeciesDropdown').change(functon(){ //Ajax call and field binding)} so I don't have not having to bind those text fields multiple times in separate change functions

Comment: Refer the 2nd and 3rd options in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627421/better-way-to-load-2-dropdown-in-mvc/28640420#28640420)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your data list object to the view as a viewbag,  you will get array object at your view, then you can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function to your array, then you will get an array matching the filter you used, then do foreach function to that array instead of the one you are getting frorm ajax and populate your dropdown 
something like this

```
//ViewBag.genericSpecies is coming from _context.ReptileSpeciesList without applying any filter
 // I use json.encode to encode your list into json object
  var AllGenericSpecies= @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.genericSpecies)); 
//then onchange 
 $('#CommonHerpsDropdown').change(function () {
        $('#SpeciesDropdown').empty();
var HerpID = $('#CommonHerpsDropdown').val();
//filter all generic species, apply the filter 
AllGenericSpecies.filter(function(spiece){
return spiece.CommonHerpId  == HerpID;
}).forEach(function(value) {
( 
 $('#SpeciesDropdown').append('<option value="' + value.SpeciesId + '">' + value.StandardName + '</option>');
                    $('#ScientificClass').val(value.ScientificClassification);
                    $('#ScientificOrder').val(value.ScientificOrder);
                    $('#ScientificFamily').val(value.ScientificFamily);
                    $('#ScientificGenus').val(value.ScientificGenus);
                    $('#ScientificSpecies').val(value.ScientificSpecies);
//end of foreach         
)};
//end of on change listener 
)});
```