# Dropdown options change when value selected on another dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I have 2 drop-down lists, when i select category in categoriesDDL it needs to show layouts only for that category in layoutsDDL. Also i need to make it to be dynamic because i will add function for creating and deleting layouts in admin panel.

My tables and columns are.

```
Table Category
CategoryID CategoryName

Table Layout
LayoutID LayoutName CategoryID
```

ViewModel

```
public class LaysCatsPosts
    {
        public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public List<Layout> Layouts { get; set; }
        public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }
```

Dropdowns

```
@Html.DropDownList("LayoutsDDL", new SelectList(Model.Layouts, "LayoutID", "LayoutName"));

@Html.DropDownList("CategoriesDDL", new SelectList(Model.Categories, "CategoryID", "CategoryName"));
```

Comment: If you wanting to implement cascading dropdownlists,refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627421/better-way-to-load-2-dropdown-in-mvc/28640420#28640420) for an example but there does not seem to be a relationship between Categories and Layouts in your db so very unclear what you actually want

Comment: sorry for my poor explanation , i edited question hope its more clear now.

Comment: Then read the link I gave you - and also refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym) for a full implementation of cascading dropdownlists

Comment: Thanks a lot for help again, u helped me a lot so far.