# How to pass value between two SelectList foreach loops

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have First Loop that display data in SelectList that goes like this

```
 <select id="Select1" size="10" name="SeriesID" class="form-control" data-live-search="true">
     @foreach (var series in Model)
     {
      <option value="@series.SeriesID">@series.Series_Title</option>
     }
 </select>
```

Now i want when i select data from Select1 in SelectList to get @series.SeriesID and pass
that value in second loop.

You will notice that in second loop (Select2) i have manual put ID 163, i want to pass @series.SeriesID insted of 163 from first loop

```
<select id="Select2" size="10" name="SeasonID" class="form-control">
    @foreach (var series in Model.Select(s=>s.Seasons))
    {
        foreach (var season in series.Where(s => s.SeriesID == 163))
        {
             <option value="@season.SeasonID">@season.Name</option>
        }
    }
</select>
```

Comment: You cant. Razor is server side code. To respond to client side events (i.e selecting an option in the first dropdownlist), you need to use javascript.

Comment: You want to implement cascading dropdownlists. Refer [better way to load 2 dropdown in mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627421/better-way-to-load-2-dropdown-in-mvc/28640420#28640420) for some options, and [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym) for how to implement it and bind to your model

Comment: Thanks for directions now i know what i need to do ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have manage to find solution.

1. Create Controller that will return Json string from Model(Sql
   table).

---

```
HttpGet]
        public JsonResult GetSeason(int ID)
        {

            db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            List<Season> season = db.Seasons.Where(s => s.SeriesID == ID).ToList();

            return Json(season, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

---

2. Create Jquery function that will call GetSeason controller

---

```
$(function () {
        $("#Select1").change(function () {

            var ID = $("#Select1").val();

            var zahev = $.get("/Serije/GetSeason/" + ID);

            zahev.done(function (rezultat) {
                $("#Select2").empty();
                $.each(rezultat, function (index, row) {

                    $("#Select2").append("<option value = '"+ row.SeasonID +"'>"+ row.Name +"</option>");
                })
            });
        });
    });
```