# Dropdown does not save value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I previously asked a question in saving values as my code was removing the last value in an array, then I realized the part where it was removing the value so I changed the syntax. The problem now is that when I submit the form, it only takes the value from the second dropdown and the value from the first dropdown returns a null value. The original value from the first dropdown is combined with a delimiter like this `vehicleID_driverID` e.g. `14_2`.

Here's my new code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#VehicleID').change(function () {
          var v = $(this).val();

        //if (v == "0") {
        //    return;
        //}

        var val = v.split("_");

        var drvid = val[1];
        var vehid = val[0];

        if (drvid == "0") {
          $("#DriverID > option").each(function () {
            $(this).show();
          });
        }
        else {

          $("#DriverID > option").each(function () {
            var option_val = $(this).val();

            if (option_val != drvid) {
              $(this).hide();
            }
          });
        }

        $("#DriverID").val(drvid);
        $("#VehicleID").val(vehid);

      }).trigger("change");
    })
```

Controller:

```
        public ActionResult ReserveInitial()
    {
        ViewBag.VehicleID = db.Vehicles.Where(item => item.IsReserved == false).Select(a => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = a.VehicleID.ToString() + "_" + a.DriverID.ToString(),
            Text = a.VehicleMake + " - " + a.PlateNumber,
        });

        ViewBag.DriverID = db.Drivers.Select(a => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = a.DriverID.ToString(),
            Text = a.DriverLastName + ", " + a.DriverFirstName
        });


        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you are updating the value of first dropdown via ` $("#VehicleID").val(vehid);`. Is that intended ? What is the value of `vehdrv` and where are you getting that ?

Comment: **The original value from the first dropdown is combined with a delimiter like this vehicleID_driverID** Why ? Why not send both dropdown values separately. That is the clean and normal approach.

Comment: @Shyju:  Each vehicule may be assigned to a single driver... But a driver can drive many vehicules... That is how I see it. Discussing that is out of OP issue scope.

Comment: @Shyju I added the controller code where the options for the dropdown would be coming from. The second dropdown is supposed to be dependent on the first dropdown, as a VehicleID would be linked to a DriverID, if the DriverID is equals to 0, then the user could select from the list of Drivers, otherwise the second dropdown would only show the Driver it is connected to.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette You're on point! Sorry I should have included that in the post Thanks

Comment: So... This `change` handler is working, but on submit, you get a `null` on the back end ?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette It does not matter how your entities are related. When you have 2 form elements inside the form and when you submitt he form it will be send as 2 different items. Why would you want to create a string with 2 values and send ? That is unnecessary and make your code more complex. You do not need to create a string and send. Just send as 2 separate form element values.

Comment: In short, i do not see any reason to update the value of `VehicleID` dropdown.

Comment: Exactly... That's what I was about to say... Remove `$("#VehicleID").val(vehid);`. The options values all are `vehcule_driver`... If you force the value to `vehicule`, maybe that is what messing the submit.

Comment: Or use an hidden input to store the vehicule number only... To ease things on the backend.

Comment: What is typeof `VehicleID`? I sounds like it should be an int, which could never bind to a value that is `14_2`. But what you doing bad practice for numerous reasons, and suggest you look at [better way to load 2 dropdown in mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627421/better-way-to-load-2-dropdown-in-mvc/28640420#28640420), and if you do not want to use ajax, look at the last option

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette even if I remove that part of the code it doesn't save the value.

Comment: I solved the problem by using a hidden input suggested by @LouysPatriceBessette