# How to use Tuple in JavaScript MVC5?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying for example: when selecting from the first dropdown list "Kia brand"  I want to view just "kia models" in the second dropdown list (not to view all cars models), but it does not work. This is the code in cshtml :

```
@model Tuple< Dalili_2018.Models.Car_Model ,Dalili_2018.Models.Car_Brand >
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_EmployeeLayout.cshtml";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

 <div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Car</h4>
    <hr />

    <div class="form-group">
        @if (ViewBag.CarBrandList != null)
        {
        @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.Item2.ID, ViewBag.CarModelList 
 as SelectList, "---------", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        }
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.Item1.ID, new SelectList("  "), 
"---------", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
     }
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#Item2.ID").change(function () {
                    $.get("/CarsController/GetModelCar", { ID_car_brand: 
 $("#Item2.ID").val() }, function (data) {
                        $("#item1.ID").empty();
                        $.each(data, function (Create, row) {
                            $("#item1.ID").append("<option value='" + row.ID 
 + "'>" + row.ModelName + "</option>")
                        });
                    });
                })
            });

        </script>
```

Controller code is:

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        List<Car_Model> CarBrandList = db.Car_Brand.ToList();
        ViewBag.CarBrandList = new SelectList(CarBrandList, "ID", 
 "BrandName");

 }

 public JsonResult GetModelCar(int ID_car_brand)
    {
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;   
        List<Car_Model> CarModelList = db.Car_Model.Where(x => 
x.ID_car_brand == ID_car_brand).ToList();
        return Json(CarModelList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Comment: 1. You cannot use a `Tuple` when generating form controls in a view (a `Tuple` has no parameterless constructor so it will not bind in the POST method) - always use a view model. 2. There are multiple issues with your code - study the code in [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym) for creating cascading dropdownlists. 3. Refer also [better way to load 2 dropdown in mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627421/better-way-to-load-2-dropdown-in-mvc/28640420#28640420)

Comment: And your script will never be executed because you do not have any elements with `id="Item2.ID"" and `id="item1.ID"` (inspect the html you are generating)

Comment: thank you @StephenMuecke