# Calling specific method (not an Action) from view MVC Asp.net on on-change event of html.dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my `ASP.NET MVC` project, I have list of data saved in `ViewBag`, I am populating a `drop-down` from that where parent id null, then selecting a value from that drop down and which select data which contains their `parent_id` of selected value's id and populate another drop-down.

Note: I have stored that data in session.

I don't want to make dual call for fetching data again, so I want to make `private method` inside `controller`, and want to call that on on-change event of drop-down and load data from `ViewBag`

Or anyone can suggest quickest way by doing it with `ajax` / `jquery.`

Comment: You cannot call `private` methods on the server, they need to be `public`. And your description suggests multiple issues with your code and design. Refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym) for how to implement cascading dropdownlists, and also [better way to load 2 dropdown in mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627421/better-way-to-load-2-dropdown-in-mvc/28640420#28640420)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#parents').change(function() {
    var el = $(this),
        parent_id = el.val();

    $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetSomeList", "MyController", new {parent_id = paren_id})', function (data) {
        var ddl = $('#ddlChildDropDown');
        $.each(data, function (i, v) {
          ddl.append($('<option />', { text: v.SomeValue, value: v.SomeID}))
        })
    })
});
```

then in your controller

```
public JsonResult GetSomeList(int parent_id)
{
    var repo = new DataBaseReop()
    var my_list = repo.getListData(parent_id); // produces a list with SomeID and SomeValue

    return Json(my_list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: how to call a method like this ` private List<CLASS> GetAllData() {//code here return data; }`

Comment: I don't think you can do that. You would still need some kind of a public method helping you to accomplish that but thats a long story.

Comment: what to do if I make that method to public can I add any event on on-change condition to call that method in controller?

Comment: I have just provided you with an example on how to do that! the JsonResult method is public. it receives parent_id as a parameter and pulls out child data belonging to that parent. then returns the data as json where it is used to populate the options for an already existing dropdown on the page.