# How Load a Combo-box With Name And value from Sql table In C # Windows form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, model-view-controller

I want to make a function to load Combo-Box from SQl  Table. Actually Global Function which I can Use later one more time in My Project.

```
public static void Combo_Add_With_Value(ComboBox cbo, String sql)
{
    //List<String> List = new List<string>();
    try
    {
        SqlConnection con = new 
        SqlConnection(ConnectionInfo.GenerateString());
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        cbo.Items.Clear();
        cbo.Items.Add("");
        if (rd.HasRows)
        while (rd.Read())
        {
            cbo.Items.Add(rd[0].ToString()(object)rd[1].ToString());
        }
        rd.Close();
    }
    catch { 
    }       
}
cbo.Items.Add(rd[0].ToString()(object)rd[1].ToString());
```

In this line `Add.Show`, there are some problems, could you please advise how to fix it?

Comment: Cannot see line with ```Add.Show``` at the provided code listing

Comment: In my case, I use the ObjectDataSource. Where leads into TableAdapter which in that table, I put the select statement

Comment: winforms or asp?

Comment: Not a good idea for a function, because each combo box may have different setting. The best that you can do here is creating a function which accepts command and connection string and return you a data table. The only thing which you need is a `SqlDataAdapter`, in a `using` block which fills a `DataTable`. Setting up combo box is assigning `DataSource`, `DisplayMembet` and `ValuMember`.

Comment: Mine ASP.NET @Charlie

Comment: Possible duplicate of [better way to load 2 dropdown in mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627421/better-way-to-load-2-dropdown-in-mvc)